# Can I specify sparkSession's driver without using "option"?

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to fetch table data as DataFrame using pyspark.

The code below works, but I am wondering can I specify the name of JDBC driver, by not using `option` function in the `sparkSession.read()`

```py
ss = ( SparkSession.builder.appName(args.job_name)
            .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.0.31')
            .getOrCreate()
        )

return ss.read\
         .option("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")\
         .jdbc(url=connection_str, table=table_name, column="id", lowerBound=0, upperBound=row_cnt, numPartitions=3)
```

Can I specify `--driver-class-path` or via sparkSession config, or any other ways?

**Edit:**

I also tried using `spark.driver.extraClassPath` as [How to specify driver class path when using pyspark within a jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772350/how-to-specify-driver-class-path-when-using-pyspark-within-a-jupyter-notebook) says, but it didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify driver class path when using pyspark within a jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772350/how-to-specify-driver-class-path-when-using-pyspark-within-a-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Sadly, no :( I still need to using ‘option’ to not get jdbc driver Exception